# Few questions regarding OpenGL (culling and optimization) in a cube-based voxel engine

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using the LWJGL to create a Minecraft like voxel engine, but I'm running in to some difficulties with optimization. Now, obviously culling will probably have a great positive impact on performance, so to do back face culling I did something like this:

```
    if (chunk.getWorld().getGame().cam.getZ() >= zz) 
    {
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    }
```

And it works okay, until I run into a few problems. Invisible faces are still drawn (faces between blocks) and this doesn't exactly update if I use display lists. Here's my questions, how does one cull with display lists? I tried doing glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE); but it gave me this in return, it seems to cull front faces rather then the back:

[Culling Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjgDO.png)

[Culling Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10WPo.png)

This is with out culling enabled through glEnable, my culling disabled too (because with lists it's pointless). It all looks fine, but performance, I believe, can be greatly improved.

This is my code, if I'm missing something please ask, I can upload the whole project if you need:

EDIT: I even copied some other code to draw a cube and it still doesn't look right with culling enabled.

Comment: [Render.jar](http://pastebin.com/TwA8y451)

[Block.jar](http://pastebin.com/7D8ji1Zu)

Comment: -1, excessive indentation.

Answer (score 2):

At first - from your description

"Invisible faces are still drawn (faces between blocks) "

it appears there is a design issue. 
Whether there is a face or not should depend on the model, not on the view, and culling is a view-related concept.

---

"doesn't exactly update if I use display lists"

Look at the Chapter "What’s stored in a Display List" of the Red Book.

---

"but it gave me this in return, it seems to cull front faces rather then the back:"

Likely the normals don't fit with the polygon mode.

For cubes, calculating normals for their faces is quite cheap: simply take the cube center cc_ and the center cf_ of the face then (in pseudocode)

```
n_ = (cf_ - cc_);
n_ = normalize(n_);
```

yields an outward pointing face normal.

Comment: It's not a model, it's a bunch of cubes rendered next to each other, what red book? Can you please be more specific.

Comment: @NeHatchickVerma: "*It's not a model, it's a bunch of cubes rendered next to each other*" Which constitutes *a model*.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding drawing the faces between blocks is something you'll have to do yourself: only draw a face if the neighbouring cell in that direction is empty.

It looks like you are culling the wrong set of faces. Which faces are culled is determined by the winding order of the vertices (clockwise or anti-clockwise) after they have been transformed to screen space.

Which kind of face is considered front-facing is determined by calling `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` or `glFrontFace(GL_CCW)`. `GL_CCW` is the default.

Either reverse the order you draw the face vertices or use `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` or `glFrontFace(GL_CCW)` to change which winding order is considered front facing.

Comment: glFrontFace(GL_CW)/glFrontFace(GL_CCW) give me exactly the same result, and I did stop drawing faces between blocks, what should my cube render code look like?

Comment: Are you sure you get *exactly* the same result? If the faces don't have consistent windings (as seen from the outside of each cube) then neither GL_CW or GL_CCW will give you the correct result, but they should be differently wrong.

Comment: Another thing you could try is glCullFace with either GL_FRONT or GL_BACK (although swapping these over should have the same result as swapping GL_CW for GL_CCW).